# How to tell ffmpeg that /tmp/phpFm6H79 is a safe file name?

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I tell ffmpeg that `/tmp/phpFm6H79` is a safe filename?

When I do

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i '/tmp/phpFm6H79' -c:v:libx264 -vsync vfr '/home/hans/projects/test/output2.mp4'
```

I get (*only the last 2 lines are interesting)

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[concat @ 0x55b070e9ff40] Unsafe file name '/tmp/phpbshsmF'
/tmp/phpFm6H79: Operation not permitted
```

The filepath is generated with PHP's `tmpfile()` like

```php
$ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle = tmpfile();
$ffmpegInputTxtFilePath = stream_get_meta_data($ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle)['uri'];
```

The code should be threadsafe, so using hardcoded paths is not really viable, and using `tmpfile()` is very convenient, it takes care of automatically deleting the file when the script exit, even if php crashes, so I'd rather tell ffmpeg that it is safe, than change it to something other than `tmpfile()`, is it possible? how?

I tried using this fugly workaround to get it to end with ".txt"

```php
        $ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle = tmpfile();
        $ffmpegInputTxtFilePath = stream_get_meta_data($ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle)['uri'] . ".txt";
        fclose($ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle);
        $ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle = fopen($ffmpegInputTxtFilePath, 'w+b');
        register_shutdown_function(function () use ($ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle, $ffmpegInputTxtFilePath) {
            @fclose($ffmpegInputTxtFileHandle);
            @unlink($ffmpegInputTxtFilePath);
        });
```

but it even says that `/tmp/phpFm6H79.txt` is an unsafe filename :'(

Comment: As the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob i don't think anyone actually use the concat demuxer interactively, I certainly don't. I only use it programmatically (have thousands of images, frames of a recording, each with their own timestamp, and i need to convert them to a video, it's all done programmatically.) this is NOT a question about using ffmpeg interactively.

Answer (score -1):

add the argument `-safe 0` to disable the whole `safe file name` thing,

for some historic context, JEEB @ irc://libera.chat/#ffmpeg said

> `ffmpeg -h demuxer=concat` lists the option for that demuxer
> (which you are specifying with -f) and I think that might be
> considered unsafe due to it being a full path outside of the current
> directory or whatever, at some point people got icky with regards to
> stuff like /etc/shadow etc being poked and those were reported as
> security issues